# jupyter unable to see a docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter, host

I am a total beginner in docker and although I found a couple of questions already addressing what seems to be the same problem with mine, I can not reproduce what is proposed. 
So there is a container I want to use, in my windows 7 system. Namely: http://www.bempp.org/tutorials.html.

For windows, it proposes that you download docker. Once this is done, by pulling the appropriate notebook (done correctly as when pulled twice I get a 'already latest version'message) and then typing:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/home/bempp/work -p 8888:8888 bempp/notebook
```

is supposed to work. So I log in the local host but the list of notebooks is empty.

Output of the command is:

```
nempa001@BETA039618 MINGW64 /u

$ docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/home/bempp/work -p 8888:8888 bempp/notebook
[I 19:11:00.373 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/bemp
p/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 19:11:00.418 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP
 addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[I 19:11:00.440 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/bempp
/work
[I 19:11:00.440 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 19:11:00.441 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip
addresses on your system]:8888/?token=7313cf7a126a92a635ce49439b6344357b270e65be
b5bc6e
```

On top of that, I do not know if it is relevant, I can neither make a new notebook (error 'forbidden'returned), nor can I upload it somehow (appropriate folders empty).

Could you help? As the container seems to work from its output message, the most probable thing I suspect is that jupyter searches somewhere else for notebooks probably?

URL of jupyter is `http://192.168.99.100:8888/tree?#`

I understand the question is a mess, but I can not structure it far better, as there are many things that I do not grasp about docker and its functionality. Please be really descriptive about a probable solution.

Comment: How did you install Docker on your Windows?

Comment: As I have windows 7 (prior to windows 10), I had to download docker toolbox (legacy). After the installation, in my desktop I have, Kinematic (alpha version ) and Docker quickstart Terminal

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may be adding volume to your container which is inaccessible.

Try replacing `$(pwd)` from your `docker run` call with full path to your notebook directory, as seen from mingw shell, or `docker run` after `cd`ing into your notebook directory.

Also make sure that you added your notebook directory as a shared directory to your docker machine. For details refer to documentation: https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#optional-add-shared-directories

Comment: You are right, the path is not correct. Giving the full path, I get an error regarding lowercase and uppercase letters, which I didn't succeed in correcting. This is indeed a problem it seems, stated here in the website: ~Note: Within the VM path, c is lowercase and the Users is capitalized.~ Given that I have tried kinetik alpha and quickstart terminal and actually downloading the virtual machine itself, and all 3 face the same issue (notebook list is empty), it probably has to do something with the path. I will be back soon enough with more feedback

Comment: I created a folder named bem at the desktop, and cd 'ed at the terminal until I am at ~/bem. Again, there are no message errors. But still the server does not have any notebook in the list. So my question: What does exactly "docker pull bempp/notebook  ". It pulls an image from the docker hub, but in that case shouldn't it download some file or anything? The ~/bem folder in my desktop is empty. When I type docker images, the bempp/notebook appears in the list but I can not seem to be able to locate it in my system (and upload it manually). What type of object are images exactly?